# Could not instantiate bean class[org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution: Is it an abstract class?;

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I tried to use the following,

```
List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = getJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID,         START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED, VERSION FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION ORDER BY JOB_EXECUTION_ID ASC, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<JobExecution>(JobExecution.class));
```

It returns an exception of:

Could not instantiate bean class[org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution: Is it an abstract class?;

Anyone has any idea what is happening here? Thanks!

Comment: Is `JobExecution` an abstract class?

Comment: Does "JobExecution" has a "JobExecution()" constructor ?

Comment: No it's not an abstract class.. I'm using the spring batch JobExecution class.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find out the answer after looking through the documentation.

The mapped target class must be a top-level class and it must have a default or no-arg constructor.

For JobExecution.class, it does not have a no-arg constructor.